# Replace " " with "\ " in a file path string with variable expansion

Tags: bash, replace, expansion

I know there is a better way to do this.

1. What is the better way?
2. How do you do a string replace on a string variable in bash?

**For Example:** (using php because that's what I know)

```
$path = "path/to/directory/foo bar";

$path = str_replace(" ", "\ ", "$path");

echo $path;
```

returns:

```
path/to/directory/foo\ bar
```

Comment: Can't you just quote the path?

Comment: What are you going to do with the string once you've performed the replacement?  Do you just need to escape space characters, or all whitespace?

Comment: Are you sure you need to replace the space? If you are just assigning the path to a variable, `path="/path/to/directory/foo bar"` is fine, as long as you always quote `$path` whenever you use it.

Comment: And you should [always quote bash variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To perform the specific replacement in `bash`:

```
path='path/to/directory/foo bar'
echo "${path// /\\ }"
```

- Don't use prefix `$` when *assigning* to variables in `bash`.
- No spaces are allowed around the `=`.
- Note that `path` is assigned with *single* quotes, whereas the string replacement occurs in *double* quotes - this distinction is important: `bash` does NOT interpret single-quoted strings, whereas you can refer to variables (and do other things) in double-quoted strings; (also, not quoting a variable reference at all has other ramifications, often undesired - in general, *double-quote your variable references*)

**Explanation of string replacement** `"${path// /\\ }"`:

- In order to perform value substitution on a variable, you start with enclosing the variable name in `{...}`
- `//` specifies that ALL occurrences of the following search pattern are to be replaced (use `/` to replace the *first* occurrence only).
- `/` separates the search pattern,  (a single space), from the replacement string, `\\` .
- The replacement string, `\` , must be represented as `\\` , because `\` has special meaning as an escape char. and must therefore itself be escaped for literal use.

The above is an instance of what bash (somewhat cryptically) calls **shell parameter expansion** and also **parameter expansion** and **[parameter and] variable expansion**. There are **many more flavors**, such as for **extracting a substring, providing a default value,  stripping a prefix or suffix, ...** - see [the BashGuide page on the topic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) or [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

As for what **types of expressions are supported in the search and replacement strings**:

- The **search expression** is a **globbing pattern** of the same type used in filename expansion (e.g, `*.txt`); for instance, `v='dear me'; echo "${v/m*/you}"` yields `'dear you'`. Note that the *longest* match will be used.

  - Additionally, the *first* character of the pattern has special meaning in this context:

    - `/`, as we've seen above, causes *all* matching occurrences of the pattern to be replaced - by default, only the *first* one is replaced.
    - `#` causes the rest of the pattern to only match at the *beginning* of the input variable
    - `%` only matches at the *end*
- The **replacement expression** is a **string that is *subject to shell expansions***; while there is *no* support for backreferences, the fact that the string is expanded allows you to have the replacement string reference other variables, contain commands, with `$(...)`, ...; e.g.:

  - `v='sweet home'; echo "${v/home/$HOME}"` yields, for instance, `'sweet /home/jdoe'`.
  - `v='It is now %T'; echo "${v/\%T/$(date +%T)}"` yields, for instance, `It is now 10:05:17`.
  - `o1=1 o2=3 v="$o1 + $o2 equals result"; echo "${v/result/$(( $o1 + $o2 ))}"` yields `'1 + 3 equals 4'` (I think)

There are many more features and subtleties - refer to the link above.

Comment: Chapter 10.1 "Manipulating Strings" in the "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide" also has a good explanation and many examples:

https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: @botkop: Thanks; I've added a link to the [relevant BashGuide page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to the answer, as its presentation seems better; the BashGuide seems to be held in higher regard than the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide in general.

Answer (score 4):

How about [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html)? Is that what you're looking for?

```
#!/bin/bash

path="path/to/directory/foo bar"
new_path=$(echo "$path" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
echo "New Path: '$new_path"
```

But as [@n0rd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31782/n0rd) pointed out in his comment, is probably better just quoting the path when you want to use it; something like...

```
path="path/to/directory/foo bar"
echo "test" > "$path"
```